# How to use a Julia script from Github in my PyCharm Python project

Tags: python, github, pycharm, julia

I wish to use this julia script https://github.com/amitg7/01ChaosTest.jl/blob/master/src/01ChaosTest.jl in python. How can I directly use it in my PyCharm project.

Comment: Upvoted just for using julia.  One way is to install pyjulia, which involves a) installing a version of python that uses a shared library, b) installing julia (while your new python is activated), and c) install JuliaPy from julia, and d) from python: import julia ; julia.install()  THEN you can import julia, include the .jl file, and call its functions

Comment: pyjulia (currently v0.5.6) is the main way of using Julia inside Python. However, PyCall.jl, which does the reverse of using Python inside Julia, is more mature (v1.92.5). They're both part of the JuliaPy organization, which also includes some Julia wrappers of popular Python packages: https://github.com/JuliaPy